# Color Tint my Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using Google Maps V3 API to display my map.

**Problem:** How can I color tint the map, say blue, such that the map tiles have a blue tint to it, but the markers and other overlays do not? I do not wish to use custom-styles on the map itself which will cause me to hit the google map usage limits for styled maps quickly.

I thought of adding a blue polygon with an opacity, but figured the polygon will move off screen when you pan the map. Is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a rectangle looks pretty convincing to me, with a defect: flicker when the map is zoomed in and out. I didn't test thoroughly but you might run into layering issues, for example, being unable to click on a line that's below the rectangle. The marker, as I remember, is in a different pane so it is clickable.

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/27/

```
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-84.999999, -179.999999), 
  new google.maps.LatLng(84.999999, 179.999999));

rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    fillColor: "#0000ff",
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    map: map
});
```

Side note: I tried a KML overlay like this:

```
  <ScreenOverlay>
    <name>Dynamic Positioning: Top of screen</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://...blue.png</href>
    </Icon>
    <overlayXY x="0" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <screenXY x="0" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <rotationXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <size x="1" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
  </ScreenOverlay>
```

Would have been a winner, but you can't drag and scroll the map.

Comment: Hey Lilina, thanks for the help. I'm trying to avoid using map styles because the map usuage for styled maps is much lower. Can this be done using overlays/underlays?

Comment: Sorry for not reading the question. :( I will think of something.

Comment: Thats awesome, I get the color tint and dont see any flickr. However, the rectangle is covering over my custom image overlays (heatmap), cant seem to bring the overlay above the rectangle, or rectangle below the custom image overlays

Comment: I'm making huge assumptions about your overlay, now there's an option to set your custom image on which pane, described in the [Overlay docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Initializing) There's this line `panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);` where the layer can be chosen, try using `overlayShadow` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make the assumption you mean to embed the API into a webpage. IF that is true you could wrap the API in to a div let us say  then use a bit of CSS to fill the div with a blue color of your choosing and set the opacity of said div to maybe 0.4 or (40%). Your code would look something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="mapwrapper">MAP API EMBEDDING CODE</div>
```

CSS

```
#mapwrapper{
      opacity:0.4;
      filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
      }
```

as cited by [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

I have used it for social media /social networking connections on websites.

Again this is if you are embedding into a website, I'd ask specifically about your intent but this dang thing won't let me post a comment.

Comment: Yes I am embedding into a website, I have heatmaps generated to overlay over the map, but the overlay tiles have alot of transparent regions that I want to fill up with some color so the heatmap has a continuous colored fill for 0 weight, instead of being transparent which makes the map look splotchy

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out myself a solution that works even better than the one suggested.

My solution will prevent the flickering as well. [**Check it out in this thread!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638175/make-a-color-tinted-map-in-google-maps-v3)