# Make a color tinted map in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I have searched around the net, and found several solutions. Including [this thread here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964607/color-tint-my-google-map). However, all of the methods creates a **flicker** on the screen while zooming in/out.

Is there any way of preventing this? I'm currently applying a [ImageMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=sv#ImageMapType) as overlay. It works great, but the flickering occurs while zooming.

Are there any other alternatives to apply a color tint to the map, but not the other overlays (markers and such).

This is how I apply my ImageMapType btw:

```
var overlayTint = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {return 'library/img/maptint.png';},
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(512, 512),
    opacity: 0.30,
    isPng: true
});
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, overlayTint);
```

**EDIT:** I'm using *Satellite maps*, which implies that Styled Maps are not the way to go either.

Comment: Have you tried using a [styled map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)?

Comment: Yes. However I'm using Satellite maps, which is not supported by styled maps.

Comment: Did it say that somewhere in your question?  Maybe you could add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works pretty well!

I extended the [**OverlayView**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) class to make my own custom overlay. This overlay consists of a single `<div>` that has a half-transparent blue:ish color. The div is screensize*2, and is placed in the middle of the screen.

The reason for being twice as big is because the zoom in/out. While you are zooming in, the overlay gets relative resized to fit the *ending position*. Since the ending position is smaller, this creates a big gap around the overlay. However, if we make it twice as big as the screen, we avoid this problem!

And as the tip of the iceberg, we hook the `drag, dragend and center_changed` events to re-positionize this div to the center of the screen. This ensures that the overlay stays in place when the user pans around as well.

Hope that this can help anybody else. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Just had to solve this myself. This thread gave me quite a few pointers on where to look, but I arrived on a slightly different solution than OP.

I instead created an overlay at the bounds of Lat/Lng, which is -90, -90 to 90 90. The overlay was again, a simple div with the background set to an rgba color.

Here is my solution in coffeescript:

```
gm = google.maps
center = new gm.LatLng 50, 0
class colorOverlay extends gm.OverlayView
  constructor: (@color, @map) ->
    @div = null
    @setMap @map
    @bounds = new gm.LatLngBounds(new gm.LatLng(-90, -90), new gm.LatLng(90, 90))
  onAdd: () ->
    col = document.createElement 'div'
    col.style.width = '100%'
    col.style.height = '100%'
    col.style.position = 'absolute'
    col.style.background = @color

    @div = col
    panes = @getPanes()
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(@div)
  draw: () ->
    # Overlay Projection
    oP = @getProjection()

    sw = oP.fromLatLngToDivPixel @bounds.getSouthWest()
    ne = oP.fromLatLngToDivPixel @bounds.getNorthEast()

    div = @div
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px'
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px'
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px'
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px'



map = new gm.Map mapElem,
            zoom: 10
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            center: center
marker = new gm.Marker
               position: center
               map: map
               title: "Hello World!"

overlay = new colorOverlay 'rgba(37,41,56,0.6)', map
```